# MediaController Play button is not working?

Tags: android, android-music-player

i use the code from the link,
http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1399

where the media player is use to play the  audio, media controller is appear as anchor view of layout, the problem is while clicking  the layout media controller is appear but the play button is not working , i can`t able to start the audio;

If anyone know s the problem means help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Need more info, are you getting logcat messages or something?

Comment: the source code is available in this link  http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1399 ,no error or nothing will be logged in logcat

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , i made a mistake it is working know;
in on prepare listener of Media controller i set the property `setEnable(false)` and the second thing is i return as false in the following function

```
@Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please enter your mistake here, and mark as answered, so other people can learn from it too.

Comment: do not write comments or any thing in answer section